# Duplicate Key in Repeater, track by creates problems

Tags: angularjs

I have an object I am trying to `ng-repeat` through.

The object is something like this:

```
ctrl.obj = {
    "1": ["val1", "val2", ... ],
    "3": ["val1", "val2", ... ],
    ...
    "20": ["val1", "val2", ... ]
}
```

When I try:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in ctrl.obj"></ul>
```

I get this angular error:

```
Error: ngRepeat:dupes
Duplicate Key in Repeater
```

The standard solution is to use `track by $index`. That does not work for my scenario though, because it now causes every integer between `0` and `20` to appear, even though I only have `1`, `3`, `7`, `10`, etc. I would ideally not like to reformat the object, as it is being loaded from outside the app ~ though this seems to be a recurring necessity with Angular.

What are my options for repeating through this object?

Comment: just as a piece of information, you don't need to change your remote logic, angular got many ways of sanitizing and processing fetched data client side.

Comment: even when I attempt this using the syntax that you provided in your question, it parses correctly.  Somehow it seems as though you haven't provided an accurate representation of your object.

Comment: @Claies I see that. I am working on creating a minimal fiddle reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This object is a dictionary, where each property is a key, and each array is a value.  To iterate through this properly, you would need two separate `ng-repeat`.  something like the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in ctrl.obj">
    {{key}} : {{value}}
    <div ng-repeat="item in value">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

There may be something else going on here, because I am unable to reproduce the error you are experiencing when using this syntax, though you state that the syntax causes an error in your situation.  Can you post a sample of data which actually does cause this error?

http://plnkr.co/edit/LvvpxNqM6LuGVel4WQt9?p=preview

This plunker is using your original `<ul>`, and it is not producing any of the errors you are describing.  It seems as though you haven't provided an accurate representation of the object you are trying to display here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/xgded2Ebrf0xKFuupOyr?p=preview

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Yes, of course. My problem is that when using `(key, value) in ctrl.obj` I get the mentioned error. The second level repeat isn't even in play yet. I realize `item` is an object/array.

Comment: the exact duplicate that the angular error cites in "undefined:undefined".

Comment: eh? I'm not seeing any of this with the plunker that I created to work the issue out......